# linqtosql maintain ordering of list

Tags: c#, linq, contain

```
var convertedIds = ids.Select(id => Convert.ToInt32(id)).ToList();
return this.context.SupportedCharacterSets
    .Where(av => converteIds.Contains(av.id))
    .Select(av => new AsideItem 
                  { 
                     Id = av.id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
                     Name = av.name 
                  }).ToList();
```

convertedIds is a list of ints: `{ 2, 1 }` - for example

When I am selecting from the db, it orders it `1,2` (which is expected), is there a way to not do this? I seen you can do a `Dictionary` object, however unsure if this is overkill?

Comment: You are confusing different things. LINQ to EF or SQL actually generates a SQL statement. In your case, it's a statement with an `IN (1,2,...)` clause. There's no guarantee that the results will be returned in any order. Even in LINQ to Object though, `Where` doesn't affect order. It doesn't matter *what* the condition of `where` is.

Comment: I know it generates SQL, my question wasn't regarding what it generates, it was whether there was another way to order by the convertedIds rather than adding the convertedIds into a Dictionary object, which is what I had seen online. I also know the WHERE and ORDER BY are very different, the issue is not with the WHERE clause but with how I can ORDER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `List.IndexOf` in `OrderBy`:

```
return this.context.SupportedCharacterSets
    .Where(av => converteIds.Contains(av.id))
    .AsEnumerable()  // to get  Linq-To-Objects
    .OrderBy(av => converteIds.IndexOf(av.id))
    .Select(av => new AsideItem 
    { 
       Id = av.id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
       Name = av.name 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I doubt this would work in LINQ to EF, and it would have unexpected side effects in LINQ to SQL. The OP mentioned that the code selects from a database

Comment: Thanks, Tim you are on the ball today :-D, ill accept the answer when I can

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: that's why i've used `AsEnumerable` after `Where`. `Contains` is supported but not `IndexOf`, so you need to load the matching rows into memory.